# Use ACE editor for all text boxes in CMSMS

Tags: ace-editor, cmsmadesimple

In our CMS Made Simple installation I am using the ACE editor wherever I can (Stylesheets, Templates, and so on). Now I would like to use it in other text boxes within the admin interface as well (e.g. page content).

Is there any way to "force" the use of the ACE editor, or a module that helps me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dirty way you can add 11th parameter "true" in lib/classes/contenttypes/Content.inc.php:552, finaly this line should looks like:

```
$ret = create_textarea($block_wysiwyg, $value, $blockInfo['id'], '', $blockInfo['id'], '', $this->stylesheet, null, null, null, true);
```

(based on CMSMS 1.11.12)